# How do I get multitouch working on the touchpad on a Sony Vaio VPC-F11?

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, mouse-scroll

I have Natty running fine in my sony vaio vpc-f11 series laptop .

I tried out the instructions in [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Laptop/Sony/Vaio/FSeries/Natty#KeyboardTouchpad) page.

Now I have my touchpad configured as a generic mouse. So the vertical scrolling works fine. But I would like to have multi-touch features enabled. Questions are as follows :

- What do I do to get my touchpad recognized as a touchpad rather than the mouse ? or how do I reverse the command I did as per the webpage above ?
- How do I get multi-touch to work ? None of the pointing devices options seemed to work in the first place... which is why I tried out the instructions in the link posted above.

I am listing my xinput list to clarify my situation :

```
root@AUM:/sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop# xinput list 
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)] 
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer            id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)] 
⎜   ↳ HID 1267:c002                         id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)] 
⎜   ↳ ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse            id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)] 
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]    
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard           id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]    
    ↳ Sony Vaio Keys                        id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]    
    ↳ Video Bus                             id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]    
    ↳ Power Button                          id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]    
    ↳ UVC Camera (064e:2100)                id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]    
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Any help would be appreciated ..

Answer (score 1):

wrong answer (:
that would work (: (yea, i know it's late, i saw this while writting my question):
[Vertical Scroll doesn't work on a Sony Vaio VPCEB1S1E](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55201/vertical-scroll-doesnt-work-on-a-sony-vaio-vpceb1s1e)

you will find there this link, translate to englist and watch the original at the same time:http://blog.pavelb.ru/2011/10/ubuntu-1110-in-sony-vaio-vpceh-touchpad.html

in short (and english (: ):
open nautilus (in terminal-sudo nautlius)
go to "etc" >> "X11" >> "xorg.conf".

from like that:

Section "Device"
   Identifier "Default Device"
   Option "NoLogo" "True"
EndSection

make it look like that:

Section "Device"
   Identifier "Default Device"
   Option "NoLogo" "True"
   Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection

```
Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
```

the answer to your question:

download: http://people.canonical.com/~sforshee/alps-touchpad/psmouse-alps-0.10/psmouse-alps-dkms_0.10_all.deb

and in terminal:

**wget http://people.canonical.com/%7Esfors...s_0.10_all.deb**

**sudo dpkg -i psmouse-alps-dkms_0.10_all.deb**