# Vertical Scroll doesn't work on a Sony Vaio VPCEB1S1E

Tags: touchpad, vaio

I have an Sony Vaio VPCEB1S1E that I have dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu all 64 bit
In ubuntu I don't have vertical scroll.
Same thing happens with Fedora 15,Linuxmint11 of course 64 bit
If someone has a solution .........?

Answer (score 1):

It's known that the [touchpad of vaio-E series have problems](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/565543). However, you should at least get vertical scrolling - at least I do.

You can try editing `/etc/default/grub` and make the following change to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop"
```

then run `sudo update-grub`

If there were previous values (like `quiet splash`) to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT leave them. This will disable the multi-touch features of the touchpad (but that probably didn't work anyway.

Comment: in terminal:

sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps

if works,to keep effective this change at the next reboot:

sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf

and add this line:

options psmouse proto=imps

save and reboot

Comment: @Rolin works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I use the french version of ubuntu 11.04 with Gnome 3, but you can try this... I'm not sure of the generic word use in the english version of ubuntu.
Go into the System setting. Then, click on the Mouse and Thouchpad.
On the Touchpad tab, activate the scrolling by choosing the vertical scroll. You can check the horizontal scroll if you like it.
Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you touchpad alps, смотрите сюда http://blog.pavelb.ru/2011/10/ubuntu-1110-in-sony-vaio-vpceh-touchpad.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.