# Brightness Controls not working on Sony Vaio VGN FZ31S NVidia G8600M

Tags: xubuntu, brightness, xfce, sony

since I installed XUbuntu 12.04 on my notebook, brightness controls are no longer working (they used to work before with Smartdimmer).
I tried several suggestions, starting from gnome-settings with gsd-backlight-helper to the Xorg.conf file, but both didn't help, maybe someone can give me further advice?

Answer (score 0):

here some solution in heberw (עברית-למקרה שאתה דובר (: ): http://www.fxp.co.il/showthread.php?t=10255235&p=94282824#post94282824

also here is the source from the end of the comment there: [Vertical Scroll doesn't work on a Sony Vaio VPCEB1S1E](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55201/vertical-scroll-doesnt-work-on-a-sony-vaio-vpceb1s1e)

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't help me getting any further.

Comment: my mistake-my sorry ;) , this is ths source of the second guide there.         but this would help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/76081/brightness-not-working-after-installing-nvidia-driver                                               you should edit the file and add the line.

Comment: Sorry, but this didn't work either.
I added the line to my xorg.conf and installed the latest dkms file, still no change in brightness. Which program or command would you suggest to adjust brightness level? Do you have any further idea for a solution?

Comment: did you copy-paste it precisly? ( (: ) pay attention to all the " and ' there. may you paste your file here?                               I hope I will succesed in helping you, also hope to get more help from more people here (: