# Touchpad Issue In Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, vaio, sony

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as well as Windows 8 installed on my **Sony Vaio SVF15218SN**. My touchpad works fine in Windows but not in Ubuntu. In Ubuntu, when I slide fingers over, the touchpad cursor do not move but instead it scrolls pages up and down.
Touchpad is Synaptics.

Comment: Do you touch your touchpad with more than 1 finger?

Comment: No. Only 1 finger. If i use it with more than 1finger it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Goto **Mouse&TouchPad Settings**->Uncheck Natural scrolling.

It worked for me now my touchpad works completely fine.

And also try this [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168708/touchpad-in-sony-vaio-e14-cannot-click-with-a-finger-and-drag-with-another-u)